# Bash script loop through an array of numbers with delimiters comma + space

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

I wanna loop through the array and print out each element in a bash script:

```
array=(10, 0.2, 0.03,)
for ele in ${array[@]}
do
echo "$ele blah" 
done
```

However, it spits out:

```
10, blah
 blah
0.2, blah
 blah
0.03 blah
```

Even if I added

```
IFS=","
```

The result is :

```
10 blah
 blah
0.2 blah
 blah
0.03 blah
```

How can I get:

```
10 blah
0.2 blah
0.03 blah
```

After this, I would like to align each line like:

```
10.00      blah
0.200      blah
0.030      blah
```

> Updated:
>
> With the 1st and 2nd column separated by 6 spaces

Is there any easy way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi this will cause 10 to stretch out by one compared to 0.2 and 0.03

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the commas in your array declaration.

```
array=(10 0.2 0.03)
```

You also may want to double your expansion in the `for` loop, unless you are 100% sure there is no chance that word splitting will cause problems (note that in the case of your sample data it won't).

```
for ele in "${array[@]}"
```

To format the output, try (instead of `echo`)

```
printf "%06.3f      blah\n" "$ele"
```

You need to increase the number following the `%` sign if you need more digits before the decimal separator, and you remove the 0 to avoid printing leading zeros if you do not want them.  For instance :

```
printf "%10.3f      blah\n" "$ele"
```

Comment: I added an explanation for that at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the commas doing:

```
for ele in `echo ${array[@]} | sed 's/,//g'`;
```

Instead of

```
for ele in ${array[@]}
```

[sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) is a very useful tool for doing small manipulations in texts such as replacements with the "s" function. Definitely worth playing around with :)

For the alignment you can use tabs instead of space and printf instead of echo. So use:

```
printf "%-10.3fblah\n" $ele
```

instead of

```
echo "$ele blah"
```

Comment: Do you think the OP needs to use a separate command to remove commas instead of simply not using them in the first place?

Comment: this will cause 10 to stretch out by one compared to 0.2 and 0.03